# Not allowed to suggest edits via SE app.

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, android-app

When I tried to edit a post via the SE android app, I got the red error message 'This account is not allowed to suggest edits'.  I then tried the desktop website where it did work.

Is this a bug in the SE android app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to suggest edits through the app at present. This is a known limitation of Stack Exchange API, on which the mobile apps rely. See [Android app should send edits to edit queue if necessary rather than rejecting them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208471/) which has [status-planned](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-planned).

---

*This part is outdated, per Dave Haney's comment*

While it's true that bugs can be reported on local metas, for mobile apps it is *much* more efficient to report them on [SE Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+android-app). There's no point in scattering bug reports over 100+ per-site metas, when the subject matter has nothing to do with the sites themselves.

SE meta has the tag  `android-app` which the app developers monitor closely. We don't, and even if we had one, it's not a given that developers will immediately find it and add it to their filter.

---

*However, some points remain*

- When posting on SE Meta, one is likely to find out (via suggested duplicates) that the bug was already reported, saving  the trouble of writing a report and posting screenshots.
- Bug reports usually get a few upvotes on SE meta, and unlike on per-site metas, you get actual, shiny, precious reputation points there.

Comment: I've added the first math meta `android-app` tag to this post. We have dev tools that let us look for the tag regardless of site, so it will appear for us even on math meta.